# Delayed response while trying to connect on SQL Server with wrong name

Tags: sql-server

I am accessing an SQL Server Instance both locally and through a VPN. When I am out of the office, VPN is automatically activated.

The IP address of reaching the SQL Server is different in the above situations. I am developing an application and while testing, I would like to have 2 connection strings, one for each IP. Failing to connect with the first one would trigger another attempt with the second.  Unfortunately, when the Instance name is wrong, the reply takes a while.

Does anybody know a way to speed this up? Any name-resolution attempts that I could by-pass?

Comment: Can you not simply have a start up form with a dropdown box to select local or vpn and set your connection string accordingly? After your development phase, you simply get rid of it.

Comment: That's a very nice alternative as well! Although I still get the curiosity to know why it takes so long to take the final decision that the connection is not possible..

Comment: I am sure somewhere there is a configurable timeout. But my point is, why bother? If you know it won't work, why try?